# How to put ra eadable link in the browser by using php get method?

Tags: php, get

I create a form by using HTML & PHP. One of the input field's value is:

```
ly=0&br=0&slc=0&sdp=2&sd=0
```

But when it shows in the action page, this value is shown in the browser like

```
http://example.com/load-single.php?query=ly%3D0%26br%3D0%26slc%3D0%26sdp%3D2%26sd%3D0
```

I need it to show exactly what my value is in the URL like:

```
http://example.com/load-single.php?query=ly=0&br=0&slc=0&sdp=2&sd=0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: if you want the whole value in one variable server-side? not.

Comment: I need to show the whole value in the browser exactly like this - "example(dot)com/load-single.php?query=ly=0&br=0&slc=0&sdp=2&sd=0".